# Calling async function inside of async function results in lifetime issues

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

The function `run_av_check` receives a vector filled with URLs which need to get called using reqwest. Iterating through the URLs gives me the error that the borrowed value does not live long enough. My understanding is that as long as `check_availability` is not finished for all URLs which are called in `run_av_check` using a `for` loop the `run_av_check` function is not finished, therefore the variable URLs should still exist during the runtime of all `check_availibility` calls.

I have read the Tokio and Rust documentation but I am not able to find a clue how and why this behaviour occurs. Why does the error pop up and what needs to be changed to make this work, both program wise and in my way of thinking?

```
async fn check_availability(host: &str) -> Result<reqwest::StatusCode, reqwest::Error> {
    // ... building url
    match client.get(&url).send().await {
        Ok(r) => Ok(r.status()),
        Err(_e) => Ok(reqwest::StatusCode::GATEWAY_TIMEOUT),
    }
}

async fn run_av_check(urls: Vec<std::string::String>) -> Result<AvResponse, AvError> {
    let mut av_urls: Vec<std::string::String> = vec![];
    let mut s: std::string::String = "".to_string();
    let mut attributes = Vec::new();

    for url in urls.iter() {
        attributes.push(("instance", url));
        let resp = tokio::task::spawn(check_availability(url));
        // ... processing result
        let res = AvResponse {
            av_urls,
            prom_details: s,
        };
        Ok(res)
    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste the exact and entire error that you're getting — that will help us to understand what the problem is so we can help best. Sometimes trying to interpret an error message is tricky and it's actually a different part of the error message that's important. Please use the message from running the compiler directly, not the message produced by an IDE, which might be trying to interpret the error for you.

Comment: Skimming your code, maybe the problem is in `for url in urls.iter()`... Try `for url in urls` and and switch `check_availability` into taking a `String`.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you are starting independent tasks in `tokio::task::spawn(check_availability(url));`

This function takes [only `'static` references](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.2/tokio/task/fn.spawn.html) but your `url` refers to the local vector `urls`.

You need to make `check_availability` accept the `String` type (`fn check_availability(host: String)`) and call it like `let resp = tokio::task::spawn(check_availability(url.to_string()));`